# Waiting for request to finish then go to next

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, request

How would I get this go through the getPrice then the getMarketCap function in order, so that it displays 'price searched, marketcap searched then searches complete'? I've looked at promises, but I'm unsure of how to use them in this case.

```
const rp = require('request-promise');

var parseBody1;
var price;

var parseBody2;
var marketCapUsd;

function getPrice(website) {
    rp(website)
        .then(function (body) {
            parseBody1 = JSON.parse(body);
            price1 = parseBody1[0]['price_usd'];
            console.log('price searched');
        });
}

function getMarketCap(website) {
    rp(website)
        .then(function (body) {
            parseBody2 = JSON.parse(body);
            marketCapUsd = parseBody2[0]['market_cap_usd'];
            console.log('marketcap searched');
        });
}

$('#search-button').click(function() {
    getPrice('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/ethereum/?convert=usd');
    getMarketCap('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin/?convert=usd');
    console.log('searches complete');

    console.log(price, marketCapUsd);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions `getPrice` and `getMarketCap` should be returning promises.
Since you are already using request promise you could simply return it,

Something like

```
function getPrice(website) {
    return rp(website)
    .then(function (body) {
        parseBody1 = JSON.parse(body);
        price1 = parseBody1[0]['price_usd'];
        console.log('price searched');
    });
}
```

Also you are calling them synchronously, so `getMarketCap` will not wait for `getPrice` to complete.

In order to achieve a serial flow. You should be calling `getMarketCap` only post `getPrice` is complete.

Something like

```
getPrice('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/ethereum/?convert=usd')
.then(() => {
   return getMarketCap('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin/?convert=usd');
})
```

Comment: So I keep getMarketCap as is? It also gives me an 'cannot read property on of undefined error'.

Comment: No, you will need to update both those functions. The answer just has a demonstration around how it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
$('#search-button').click(function() {
    Promise.all([
        rp('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/ethereum/?convert=usd'),
        rp('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin/?convert=usd')
    ]).then((result)=>{
        parseBody1 = result[0];
        parseBody2 = result[1];
        price1 = parseBody1[0]['price_usd'];
        marketCapUsd = parseBody2[0]['market_cap_usd'];
        console.log('searches complete');
        console.log(price, marketCapUsd);
    })
});
```

Comment: This would not ensure the serial order which the OP asked.

Comment: It'll Start process parallel, I don't see any dependencies between both the calls. So the better approach is parallel, It'll reduce process(waiting) time.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use async/await with promises. It emulates synchronous behaviour.

Here are some examples: http://thecodebarbarian.com/common-async-await-design-patterns-in-node.js.html